# how to queue fast api requests for subsequent processing without using message brokers?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi

There is a fast api service that receives an archive with files and a url for sending the result. Since speech recognition is a time-consuming process. Now I'm sending a request, waiting for it to process, return the result, and only then I can send the next request. It is necessary to receive a request for processing, return 200 that the process has started, after processing sends the result to the url, but during processing more requests may come and I need to store them somewhere and write them to the queue. And take requests from the queue. Of course, there are tools such as kafka, rabbitmq. But I wanted to do without them.There is an idea to use a queue from `asyncio.Queue`, but no idea how to implement it.

```
@app.post("/uprecognize", tags=["Upload and recognize"], status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def upload_recognize(
        url_for_request: str,
        background_tasks: BackgroundTasks,
        file: UploadFile = File(...),
                        ):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    full_name = split_filename(file)
    if not is_archive_file(file):
        logger.error(f"File must be RAR or ZIP format")
        return JSONResponse(content={'msg': 'File must be RAR or ZIP format'}, status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        start = time.time()
        await save_file_to_uploads(file, full_name)
        end = time.time()
    if not os.path.exists(UPLOADED_FILES_PATH + '/' + os.path.splitext(full_name)[0]):
        os.mkdir(UPLOADED_FILES_PATH + '/' + os.path.splitext(full_name)[0])
    if os.path.exists(UPLOADED_FILES_PATH + '/' + full_name) and rarfile.is_rarfile(UPLOADED_FILES_PATH + '/' + full_name):
        unrar_files(UPLOADED_FILES_PATH + '/' + full_name)
    elif os.path.exists(UPLOADED_FILES_PATH + '/' + full_name) and zipfile.is_zipfile(UPLOADED_FILES_PATH + '/' + full_name):
        unzip_files(UPLOADED_FILES_PATH + '/' + full_name)
    else:
        logger.error(f"File not found")
        return JSONResponse(content={'msg': 'File not found'}, status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    background_tasks.add_task(recognition_wav, full_name, logger, model, url_for_request)
    return JSONResponse(content={'msg':'Start recognition'},
                        status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
                        background=background_tasks)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question you are just looking for a queuing mechanism for receiving, buffering, and executing tasks that you can slot your own tasks into using `asyncio.Queue`.

This accepts and buffers actions in `inq`, taking 1 at a time and processing it via `procq`. This is a runnable snippet, the output should be self-explanatory.

Your `i` will no doubt be something larger, however given asyncio is a single threaded application shared variables are simple to handle and you might hand around a file name or a dictionary key for an object collection.

```
import asyncio

async def receive(inq, procq):
    while True:
        new = await inq.get()
        print(f"receive and hand off {new}")
        await procq.put(new)

async def process(procq):
    while True:
        proc = await procq.get()
        print(f"process {proc}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # process the action

async def create(inq):
    for i in range(10):
        print(f"create {i}")
        await inq.put(i)  # some pretend actions
    pass  # exit, would accept other sources in a real program

async def main():
    inq = asyncio.Queue(5)  # only hold up to five
    procq = asyncio.Queue(1)  # only process one at a time
    await asyncio.gather(
        process(procq),
        receive(inq, procq),
        create(inq)
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: requests are submitted to me for input, it takes time to process them and only then return the result. What should I use? In my view, what it looks like, I receive requests for processing, give out the answers that I received, write these requests to the queue and process the requests in parallel, after each processed request I send the result to the client. Preferably without message brokers. But I will take into account any suggestions